# Django Intermittent error occurring on db write

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django 1.6 app running on gunicorn with nginx. I'm getting an error intermittantly, it seems to occur on any page that writes to the database.

The error is:

`Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute '\__newobj__'`

```
Traceback:
File "/home/django/venvs/cantifix-direct/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/django/apps/cantifix-direct/products/views.py" in dispatch_product_form
  359.             return cls.as_view()(request)
File "/home/django/venvs/cantifix-direct/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/django/venvs/cantifix-direct/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in dispatch
  236.         response = super(WizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/django/venvs/cantifix-direct/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/django/venvs/cantifix-direct/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py" in post
  272.         management_form = ManagementForm(self.request.POST, prefix=self.prefix)
File "/home/django/venvs/cantifix-direct/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __init__
  100.         self.fields = copy.deepcopy(self.base_fields)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py" in deepcopy
  174.                 y = copier(memo)
File "/home/django/venvs/cantifix-direct/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __deepcopy__
  144.                                for key, value in self.items()])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py" in deepcopy
  174.                 y = copier(memo)
File "/home/django/venvs/cantifix-direct/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py" in __deepcopy__
  188.         result = copy.copy(self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py" in copy
  88.             rv = reductor(2)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /products/configure/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute '__newobj__'
```

I'm getting this maybe 1 in 3 times of all pages that write to the database, it's very strange.

here is models from one of my apps:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6648fd6233717c11a462

here is my views.py

```
import json
from itertools import groupby

from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView, FormView, UpdateView
from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login


from prices import Price

from core.utils import DistanceAwareJSONEncoder, is_expert, apply_vat
from .models import (Product, ProductCustomisation, ProductConfiguration,
                     PROJECT_TYPE_CHOICES, PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICES,
                     OptionsRecommendation, ProductGroup)
from .mixins import ProductOptions
from sales.models import Estimate, Pallet
from . import forms
from customer.models import Address
from delivery.models import DeliveryMethod


class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Product


class ProductGroupListView(ListView):
    model = ProductGroup
    template_name = 'products/product_groups.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductGroup.objects.filter(hidden=False).order_by('name')


class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'products/product_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(hidden=False, 
                                      group=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('name')


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


class GetRangesMixin(object):
    def get_dimension_ranges(self):
        return {'max_width': self.product.max_frame_width_mm,
                'min_height': self.product.min_frame_height_mm,
                'max_height': self.product.max_frame_height_mm,
                'min_width': self.product.min_frame_width_mm}


class ProductWizardMixin(GetRangesMixin):

    def get_recommended_options(self, proj_type, prop_type):
        if proj_type is not None:
            proj_type = str(proj_type)
        if prop_type is not None:
            prop_type = str(prop_type)
        product = self.get_form_instance(self.steps.current).product
        proj_name = dict(PROJECT_TYPE_CHOICES).get(proj_type)
        prop_name = dict(PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICES).get(prop_type)
        try:
            proj = product.options_recommendation.get(type=proj_type)
        except OptionsRecommendation.DoesNotExist:
            proj = None
        try:
            prop = product.options_recommendation.get(type=prop_type)
        except OptionsRecommendation.DoesNotExist:
            prop = None
        recommendations = {}
        for name in ProductOptions.get_fields():
            proj_val, prop_val = (getattr(proj, name, None),
                                  getattr(prop, name, None))
            text = []
            if proj_val:
                text.append("project type (%s)" %proj_name.lower())
            if prop_val:
                text.append("property type (%s)" %prop_name.lower())
            if not len(text):
                continue
            text = 'Recommended due to ' + ' and '.join(text)
            recommendations[name] = (proj_val or prop_val, text)
        return recommendations

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = self.get_all_cleaned_data()
        session = self.request.session
        self.instance.apply_option_switches()
        self.instance.save()
        if self.request.user.is_anonymous():
            session['project_type'] = form_data.get('project_type')
            session['property_type'] = form_data.get('property_type')
        else:
            user_profile = self.request.user.profile
            user_profile.default_project_type = form_data.get('project_type')
            user_profile.default_property_type = form_data.get('property_type')
            user_profile.save()
        approx = form_data.get('approx_dimensions', False)
        session['approx_dimensions'] = approx
        session['product_customisation_id'] = self.instance.id
        session.save()
        return redirect('products_product_summary')

    def get_template_names(self):
        template_name = 'products/%s_%s.html' %(self.template_prefix,
                                                self.steps.current)
        return [template_name, 'products/wizard_base.html']

    @property
    def product(self):
        try:
            return self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('product').get('product')
        except:
            return None

    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = ProductCustomisation(product=self.product)
        return self.instance

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductWizardMixin, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['product'] = self.product
        context['steps'] = [(s.replace('_', ' ').capitalize(), s==self.steps.current)
                            for s in self.steps.all]
        return context

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        data = super(ProductWizardMixin, self).get_form_initial(step)
        data['user'] = self.request.user
        if step == self.project_type_step:
            if self.request.user.is_anonymous():
                data['project_type'] = self.request.session.get('project_type',None)
                data['property_type'] = self.request.session.get('property_type',None)
            else:
                data['project_type'] = self.request.user.profile.default_project_type
                data['property_type'] = self.request.user.profile.default_property_type
        if step == 'product':
            data['product_id'] = self.request.GET.get('product')
        return data


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


class GuidedView(ProductWizardMixin, SessionWizardView):

    template_prefix = 'guided'
    approx_dimensions_step = 2
    project_type_step = 'project_type'

    instance = None
    _product = None
    _recommendations = None

    form_list = [
        ('project_type', forms.ProjectTypeForm),
        ('product', forms.ProductForm),
        ('dimensions', forms.DimensionsForm),
        ('configuration', forms.ConfigurationForm),
        ('options', forms.OptionsForm),
    ]

    def get_form_initial(self, step):
        data = super(GuidedView, self).get_form_initial(step)
        if step == "configuration":
            form_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('dimensions')
            data['width'] = form_data['width']
        elif step == 'product':
            form_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step(self.project_type_step)
            if form_data:
                data['project_type'] = form_data['project_type']
                data['property_type'] = form_data['property_type']
        elif step == "options":
            for name, (val, _) in self.recommendations.items():
                data[name] = val
        return data

    @property
    def recommendations(self):
        if self._recommendations is None:
            product = self.get_form_instance('options').product
            form_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('project_type')
            proj_type = form_data['project_type']
            prop_type = form_data['property_type']
            self._recommendations = self.get_recommended_options(
                proj_type,
                prop_type
            )
        return self._recommendations

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(GuidedView, self).get_context_data(form,**kwargs)
        if self.steps.current == 'dimensions':
            context['ranges'] = self.get_dimension_ranges()
        if self.steps.current == 'options':
            form_data = [(form[field], self.recommendations.get(field, None))
                         for field in form.fields]
            context['form_data'] = form_data
        return context


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


class ExpertView(ProductWizardMixin, SessionWizardView):

    template_prefix = 'expert'
    approx_dimensions_step = 1
    project_type_step = 'customisation'

    _product = None
    instance = None


    form_list = [
        ('product', forms.ProductForm),
        ('customisation', forms.ExpertForm),
    ]

    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExpertView, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)
        if self.steps.current == 'customisation':
            context['ranges'] = self.get_dimension_ranges()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return super(ExpertView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        proj_type = request.POST.get('customisation-project_type')
        prop_type = request.POST.get('customisation-property_type')
        recommendations = self.get_recommended_options(proj_type, prop_type)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(recommendations),
                            content_type='application/json')


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


class ProductSummaryView(FormView):

    form_class = forms.SummaryForm
    template_name = 'products/summary.html'

    @property
    def approx_dimensions(self):
        return self.request.session.get('approx_dimensions', False)

    def get_initial(self):
        self.custom = get_custom(self.request)
        return {'user': self.request.user,
                'address': self.request.GET.get('address'),
                'method': self.request.GET.get('method', 1)}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductSummaryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = kwargs['form']
        approx_dimensions = self.approx_dimensions
        context['user'] = self.request.user
        context['custom'] = self.custom
        context['total_cost'] = self.custom.total_price
        context['approx_dimensions'] = approx_dimensions
        form_data = getattr(form, 'cleaned_data', None)
        if form_data and not form.errors:
            method = form_data.get('delivery_method')
            delivery = self.estimate_delivery(
                method,
                address=form_data.get('delivery_address'),
                postcode=form_data.get('delivery_postcode')
            )
        else:
            method = DeliveryMethod.objects.get(id=1).name.lower()
            delivery = Price(0, currency='GBP')
        context['delivery_method'] = method
        context['delivery_price'] = delivery
        return context


    def estimate_delivery(self, method, address=None, postcode=None):
        if address is None:
            address = '%s, UK' %postcode
        backend = method.get_backend()(
            destination=address,
            num_items=1, # TODO only one item per product?
            weight=self.custom.total_weight,
            longest_length=self.custom.longest_length_mm
        )
        val = backend.get_charge_excl_tax()
        return Price(net=val, gross=apply_vat(val), currency='GBP')


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class EditProductViewBase(UpdateView, GetRangesMixin):

    model = ProductCustomisation
    form_class = forms.ExpertForm
    template_name = 'products/expert_customisation.html'

    def get_initial(self, **kwargs):
        return {'user': self.request.user,
                'approx_dimensions': self.approx_dimensions}

    @property
    def reverse_args(self):
        return None

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse(self.reverse_url, kwargs=self.reverse_args)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.apply_option_switches()
        return super(EditProductViewBase, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EditProductViewBase, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        self.product = self.object
        context['ranges'] = self.get_dimension_ranges()
        context['cancel_url'] = self.get_success_url()
        return context


class EditProductView(EditProductViewBase):
    reverse_url = 'products_product_summary'

    @property
    def approx_dimensions(self):
        approx = self.request.session.get('approx_dimensions', 'approx')
        return 'approx' if approx else 'exact'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_custom(self.request)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def dispatch_product_form(request):
    if request.GET.has_key('mode'):
        cls = None
        if request.GET['mode'] == 'guided':
            cls = GuidedView
        elif request.GET['mode'] == 'expert':
            cls = ExpertView
        if cls is not None:
            return cls.as_view()(request)
    product = request.GET.get('product')
    query = 'mode=guided%s' %('&product=%s'%product if product is not None
                              else '')
    return redirect('%s?%s' %(reverse('products_product_configure'), query))


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def get_custom(request):
    custom_id = request.session.get('product_customisation_id', None)
    return get_object_or_404(ProductCustomisation, id=custom_id)


def remove_custom(request):
    request.session.pop('product_customisation_id', None)


@login_required
def create_estimate(request):
    return add_for_model(Estimate, request)


@login_required
def create_pallet(request):
    return add_for_model(Pallet, request)

@login_required
def add_to_estimate(request, estimate=None):
    return add_for_model(Estimate, request, estimate)


@login_required
def add_to_pallet(request, pallet=None):
    return add_for_model(Pallet, request, pallet)


def add_for_model(model, request, id=None):
    custom = get_custom(request)
    kwargs = {}
    if model == Estimate:
        kwargs['approx_dimensions'] = request.session.get(
            'approx_dimensions',
            False
        )
    if id is not None:
        obj = get_object_or_404(model, id=id)
        if obj.user!=request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        obj = model.objects.create(user=request.user)
    obj.add_item(custom, **kwargs)
    remove_custom(request)
    return redirect(reverse('sales_user_%s_detail' %model.__name__.lower(),
                            args=(obj.id,)))
```

Comment: Post your Models code. The issue is in there

Comment: *all* my models code?! there is a lot.

Comment: I have added a link above, what makes you think the error is in there?

Comment: What's at /products/configure/

Comment: just a form view, the strange thing is that I get the same error on loads of different views

Comment: What's the code for /home/django/apps/cantifix-direct/products/views.py

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, if its happen on loads of different views, you need to do some more testing to see what specifically is triggering it. Is it every 3rd pageview, every view that hits a particular model, every view on an alternate Wednesday that is also a bank holiday? **Basically, you need to be able to reproduce this problem *at will* if you are ever to have a chance at solving it!!**

Comment: @TimRich It looks like at some point, a module has been set as the value of a field and when Django tries to deep copy the form, it fails on trying to copy the module. I'm not about to read the code line by line to hunt for this, though.